# Print variable like java in C++

Tags: java, c++

My code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int n=2;

    std::cout << "hello world"+n<<std::endl;
    printf("hello world");
}
```

I was trying to print the variable C++ like java Syntax, just as an experiment.
But output:

```
llo world
hello world
```

can anyone explain this?

Comment: C++ is not Java, and in C++ it's the formatted output operator, `<<` which is used to format output.

Answer (score 5):

`"hello world"` is a `const char[12]` type. That *decays* to a `const char*` type when it's an argument to the `+` operator.

*Pointer arithmetic* is then applied to that `const char*` type, and the overloaded `ostream` operator `<<` for a `const char*` pointer outputs the characters starting at that new pointed-to position: `n` characters from the start of the character array.

If you find `std::cout << "hello world" << n << std::endl;` objectionable and would rather put `+` into some sort of *concatenation mode* (which in Java is little more than a kludge; operator overloading is not implemented in Java with the exception of `java.lang.String`), then use

```
std::cout << "hello world" + std::to_string(n) << std::endl;
```

Then the `std::string` overloaded `+` taking a `const char*` is used, and the lower precedence of `<<` compared with binary `+` comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to obtain here, but my guess is you would like your output to look like following:

> Hello world 2

> Hello world

If so, then you would need to inject your variable into the cout command. To do
that you should modify

`std::cout << "hello world"+n<<std::endl;`

to the form of:

`std::cout << "hello world"<< n <<std::endl;`

You can read more on printing variables [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone explain this?

I C++ a string literal gives you a pointer to the first character of the string. And C++ does pointer arithmetic. So `"hello world"+n` adds 2 to the pointer since `n` is 2. The result is a pointer to the third character of the string, the first `l`. So when you print this, C++ prints the remainder of the string from that point up to the terminating null character. Thus you get `llo world`. And the 2 is not printed.

Instead you wanted (as other answers also say)

```
std::cout << "hello world" << n << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can output it in c++ using

cout<<"hello world"<<n;

Or in c using

printf("hello world %d", n);

Answer (score -1):

This is directly dependent on the syntax of C++. In your case compiler of C++ will add the value of n to your string hello world . C++ compiler is made to do this but in java the compiler and interpreter have different operation for '+' sign .

You have also used printf() in your C++ program . I is working now but will be confusing for the long run.